# Pentaho Data Integration 8.1.0.0 - microsoft excel transformation error "Get Sheetname(s)"

Tags: integration, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm taking a course and using the Pentaho Data Integration software in version 8.1.0.0 and in the course I have to do a microsoft excel transformation, in which I select a file "customers.xlsx" that already has some data, made available in the course. I'll post a screenshot of the transformation settings below, and after clicking on the "!Sheet" tab and clicking on the "Get Sheetname(s)" button, an error window appears, which I'll post a screenshot of the detailed errors.

If anyone can help me with this, I need to continue the course and I'm stuck because of this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZpXM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zwGX.png)

For now I haven't tried anything, I'm still researching, because I'm just starting out with the software, I'm doing a course at the moment, and I ended up falling into this error.

Comment: First click "show filenames" on files tab to see if it can find the excel based on the path you gave.